# Is it ok to reference self.var in a parent class with the expectation it will be implemented in the child class?

Tags: python, oop, python-class

I have some classes that look like this.

```py
class Parent:
    def f(self, x):
        # Is this bad practice?
        return x * self.number
    
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, number):
        # We create number in Child.
        self.number = number

child = Child(2)
child.f(3) # 6 - this runs
```

It seems to be going against *'explicit is better than implicit'* to define `self.number` in `Parent` without any indication that you must override it in `Child`. But it does run.

What's the best way to handle this? I could define it in `Parent`'s `__init__` but the user will only need to refer to `Child` and I don't want to duplicate the params passed to `Parent` and `Child`.

Comment: The proper way is to make `Parent` an abstract class with an abstract attribute. See the duplicate above for how to declare abstract attributes.

Comment: I don't know that it even needs to be abstract. Just have `Parent.__init__` initialize the value, so that child classes need only use `super().__init__` (if they override `__init__` at all) to pass an appropriate value.

Comment: If you design your classes using the advice from https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/, you *don't* duplicate `number` in `Child` at all.